# React - Sticky Footer issue: Footer at bottom of App component; App component not at bottom of Body

Tags: html, css, reactjs, footer, sticky-footer

I'm having some trouble with a sticky footer in react. I implemented the flexbox solution I saw on CSS Tricks, but the problem is The footer is at the bottom of the main App component, but the App component is not at the bottom of the body. Here's a picture that illustrates this problem:

[image]

Some code:
In the render function of my App component I'm returning this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="all-but-footer">
        <Header />
          <main className="content">
            <Switch>
              <Redirect from="/" to="/bio" exact />
              <Route path="/bio" exact component={Bio} />
            </Switch>

            <Route path="/videos" exact component={Videos} />
            <Route path="/gallery" exact component={Gallery} />
            <Route path="/magnet-podcast" exact component={MagnetPodcast} />
          <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
        </main>
      </div>

    <Footer />
  </div>
```

And of course I'm hooking into the root div with:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  const root = document.getElementById('root');

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Root />, root);
  registerServiceWorker();
});
```

With the root div in my index.html like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>Louis Kornfeld</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

In my CSS I tried giving the App a height of 100% and even tried giving the root div in the index.html a height of 100%. The body's only child is the root div, and the root div's child is App, so I figured giving these all height of 100% would stretch the components but nothing has worked.

Any ideas with how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Try `100vh`,  and inspect what is this blank space.

Comment: Also, can you update the question with the styles for this elements: body, root div, App div(if it's the only child of root div) and children of App div? This will really help!

Comment: So do you want to place the footer at the bottom of the body ?

Comment: @Aaqib yes, I want the footer to be at the bottom of the page with no space underneath.

Comment: I have answered your question below you just need to make use of getElementByTagName and put the wrap the portal around sticky footer or the component you want to make appear at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

Normally, when you return an element from a component’s render method, it’s mounted into the DOM as a child of the nearest parent node

If you want to to insert a child into a different location in the DOM , You can make use [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

The one which worked for me is [react-portal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-portal) you can install it as a project dependency `npm install --save react-portal`

And inside your component you can :

```
    import { Portal } from 'react-portal';

    <Portal>
      This text is portaled at the end of document.body!
    </Portal>

    <Portal node={document && document.getElementById('youCanSelectAnyIdFromTheDOM')}>

    This text is portaled into San Francisco!
   </Portal>
```

You can read more about `react-portal` [Here](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal)